# question about selling metal closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Related to this question:

[How to get a fair market price for small amounts of physical precious metals?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/120538/how-to-get-a-fair-market-price-for-small-amounts-of-physical-precious-metals)

A user rightly commented on this question to say product recommendations are off topic. As I thought it was an interesting question I edited out the product recommendation, and the edit was approved.

Since then it's been closed as off topic. Could someone please have another look at the question and suggest which part of it might still be considered to be off topic and maybe recommend what further editing would be needed to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've reopened it (though in general you should just use reopen votes/flags to get this reviewed through the review queues).

It still seems a bit like "give me a recommendation" but I agree there's a higher-level question about how to go about it/what *kinds* of providers to use that is on-topic.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. I looked for the option to vote but couldn't see it so I'm guessing I don't have enough rep yet

Comment: Is there any option somewhere under the "flag" tree?

Comment: looks like I would need 3k rep https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges - maybe one day :)

Comment: I thought that's for voting, but even if you can't vote yourself you can flag it in a way that pushes it into the reopen review queue. I'll try to remember to check the documentation/meta.se later.

Comment: ah ok got it thanks

Comment: The question was closed by a moderator, so it is not unreasonable for someone to think that a meta discussion question is more appropriate than a moderator flag for something like this.